# regex extract word in path

Tags: regex, path

I need a regex for get a word in a path

example:
(update)

```
/var/log/rsyslog/apache/test1/2014/05/file1.log
/var/log/rsyslog/apache/test2/2014/05/file2.log
/var/log/rsyslog/apache/test3/2014/05/file3.log
```

the output should be

```
test1
test2
test3
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: [`(?<=/)[^/]*?(?=[.]\w+$)`](http://regex101.com/r/lX9cF3)

Comment: Are you doing it in Linux?

Comment: Thx Sam for your answer but it's not the string i want to be receive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language you're using, in general, this regex works:

```
/\/(.*?)\.log/
```

***Regex Explanation***

```
/(.*?)\.log

Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the characters “log” literally «log»
```